# Custom System.Collections.Generic.Contains For Testing Custom Object

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I rewrite or is there a way to writing my own custom function that simulates the Custom System.Collections.Generic.Contains but only factors in certain Public Properties of a Custom Object?

For example if I have a custom Object with Properties Name and ID, I would like my Unique Value List to contain all the DISTINCT Names. The ID in this case is irrelevant.

```
List allvalues = new List ({0, "Burger"}, {1, "Pizza"}, {2, "burger"})
```

I would like it to return me a List which contains the first Object of 0, Burger and 1, Pizza... Irrespective of the ID and the Case of the Name.

Comment: I have no access to LINQ :(. Just to clarify, I need the ability to return an unique list of custom Object in a provided list. I took the code Contains from another tutorial and thought it might be applicable to this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  use yield return as in:

```
   private Collection<T> internalCollection;

    public Collection<T> GetDistinctList<T>()
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        foreach(T thisT in internalCollection)
           if (!names.Contains(thisT.Name)
           {
               names.Add(thisT.Name);
               yield return thisT;
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very unclear how the `Contains(...)` related to the `List ({0, "Burger"}, {1, "Pizza"}, {2, "burger"})` stuff. Can you clarify? In general, you might want to look at providing a custom `Equals()`/`GetHashCode()`, or `IEquatable<T>`, or an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Alternatively, LINQ has lots of ways to make this simple - do you have access to LINQ?